# How to compile JSP using Ant build and Java 11?

Tags: java, jsp, build, ant, java-11

[image]I am doing the migration from `JAVA 1.8` to `JAVA 11`. I have installed the latest `apache-tomcat-9.0.24` and `apache-ant-1.10.7`. I am using Ant to build the project.I found that .java files are compiling but some how `.jsp` files are not compiling. It is throwing error. After investigating some time I found that java has removed `tools.jar` from its `lib` folder. Could some one please tell me what will be change required in `build.xml` file so that I can compile the jsp.

```
<target name="compile_jsp" depends="compile_debug">

     <jasper validateXml="false" 
            uriroot="${web_root.dir}" 
            webXmlFragment="${build.jsp.dir}/Web_root/WEB-INF/web-fragment.xml" 
            outputDir="${build.jsp.dir}/Web_root" /> 

    <javac deprecation="false" 
            includeantruntime="false" 
            nowarn="false" 
            destdir="${build.jsp.dir}/Web_root" 
            srcdir="${build.jsp.dir}/Web_root"
            source="11" 
           target="11"> 
      <classpath refid="classpath.jspc"/> 
     </javac> 
  </target>

<path id="classpath.jspc">
    <pathelement location="${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar"/>
    <path refid="classpath.jasper_compiler" />
    <fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/bin">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${weblogic12.lib.dir}" erroronmissingdir="false">
      <include name="*javax.mail*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>
```